# GITLAB API Create new file in repository

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, gitlab-api

So i am trying to create a new file in my git repo through this api which i exposed in my react code base and i am getting 403 error? Let me know where i am wrong.

```
var bodyData = {
      token: "**********",
      ref: "main",
      branch: "demo",
      commit_message: "create a new file",
      content: "some content"
    };
    fetch("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/27622003/repository/files/myfile1%2Etxt", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("response:", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
```

Comment: im not familiar with gitlab so this is not an answer however from my experience error 403 means that you are providing the correct token however your API is not authorized to make that call to Gitlab. I'm assuming there is a step you need to do to allow your API to make that call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the actions array which includes the type of action (create, move, update, and delete) you want to do.

GitLab Commits API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html

In your case, the payload should be like following:

```
var bodyData = {
  token: "**********",
  ref: "main",
  branch: "demo",
  commit_message: "create a new file",
  actions: [
      {
         "action": "create",
         "file_path": "your/file/path",
         "content": "some content"
      }
  ]
};
```